# Unable to save the inline editing - LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an JS for Inline Edit.While Saving it throws an error.

```js
import { LightningElement,track,wire,api } from 'lwc';
import getPlantedList from '@salesforce/apex/PlantedController.getPlantedList';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import ACRE from '@salesforce/schema/Acre_Products__c.Acre__c';
import PRODUCT from '@salesforce/schema/Products__c.Planted_Product__c';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Products__c.Id';
import POTENTIAL from '@salesforce/schema/Products__c.Potential__c';
import PLANTEDACRES from '@salesforce/schema/Products__c.Planted_Acres__c';
import YIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Products__c.Yield__c';


const columns = [
    { label: 'Acre', fieldName: 'Acre__c', type: 'string',editable : 'true'},
    { label: ‘Name’, fieldName: 'Planted_Product__c' , type: 'number',editable : 'true'},
    { label: 'Potential', fieldName: 'Potential__c', type: 'number',editable : 'true'},
    { label: ‘Planted Acre', fieldName: 'Planted_Acres__c', type: 'number',editable : 'true'},
    { label: 'Yield', fieldName: 'Yield__c', type: 'String',editable : 'true'}
];

export default class PlantedAcreComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api error;
    @api columns = columns;
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
     @wire(getPlantedList)
    plantedAcre;
    handleSave(event) {
    const fields = {};
        fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = event.detail.draftValues[0].Id;
        fields[PRODUCT.fieldApiName] = event.detail.draftValues[0]. Planted_Product__c;
        fields[POTENTIAL.fieldApiName] = event.detail.draftValues[0].Potential__c;
        fields[YIELD.fieldApiName]=event.detail.draftValues[0].Yield__c;
        component.set("v.draftValues", component.get("v.dataNew "));
        const recordInput = {fields};
        updateRecord(recordInput)
        .then(() => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new showToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'updated',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            this.draftValues = [];
            return refreshApex(this.seededAcres);
        }).catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new showToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error creating record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
    } 

}
```

Comment: Please add the error or try to debug the code.

Comment: [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
newErrorHandler()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs138/auraFW/javascript/kHqYrsGCjDhXliyGcYtIfA/aura_proddebug.js:50217:14
errorHandlerWrapper()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs138/auraFW/javascript/kHqYrsGCjDhXliyGcYtIfA/aura_proddebug.js:50233:25
cn.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs138/auraFW/javascript/kHqYrsGCjDhXliyGcYtIfA/aura_proddebug.js:8666:28
cn.handleInlineEditSave()@